# Visual Studio Code - Node debugger breakpoints not being hit

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to use VSCode to debug a node app I am running.

I launch the app in a separate terminal and then use the attach to process configuration to hook into it.

The attaching works correctly and I get a side panel that says 'loaded scripts' with the files in my project.  If I click on one of those and set breakpoints there it will work correctly.

If I set a breakpoint on a file I open through the VSCode editor the breakpoint is greyed out and when I hover over it will say 'Breakpoint set but not yet bound'.

How can I make it so that the breakpoints I set on the code are bound?

Comment: After experiencing this problem myself, I tried a few variations of launch configs in order to resolve, but to no avail. In the end, reinstalling VS Code "fixed" the issue for me. Good luck to anyone else struggling with this.

Comment: Cmd+Shift+P then "**Debug: JavaScript Debug Terminal**" and run your Node code from that terminal, not from the "View: Toggle Terminal" terminal.

Answer (score 22):

Try this configuration in your launch file:

```json
{
    "name": "Attach to Process",
    "type": "node",
    "protocol": "inspector",
    "request": "attach",
    "stopOnEntry": false,
    "port": 5858,
    "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "remoteRoot": "/somepath/myprojectroot",
    "sourceMaps": true
}
```

Make sure the `remoteRoot` is correct path, otherwise it won't know where to look for the source files.

Comment: It's just as important to double check the `localRoot` path is correct. The same symptoms will occur if this is not pointing to the corresponding code base.

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what should be the "remoteRoot" path please ? how is it different from ${workspaceRoot} ?

Comment: @JJP, I guess and specified mine with `"remoteRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"` and it worked.

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar problem, I fixed it by appending `/src` to the  `"webRoot"` path.

---

Originally my `"webRoot"` property read:

```
 "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
```

Now my `webRoot` path reads:

```
"webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
```

---

#### Here is my **`./.vscode/launch.json reads:`**

```
    {
      // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
      // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
      // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
      "version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [
        {
          "type": "chrome",
          "request": "launch",
          "name": "Launch Chrome",
          "url": "http://localhost:3000",
          "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
          "trace": true
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: "Type Chrome is not allowed."

Comment: @kwoxer: You have to first install the Chrome development extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome).

Comment: Nice hint. Indeed. With this extension at least this is working. Thank you. This should be added here in the Solution.

Comment: `"trace": true` is the secret sauce.  Otherwise, you can add the `debugger;` statement for it to activate.

Answer (score 14):

On the VSCode settings search for 'debug javascript use preview', and then disable it. It should now bound all breakpoints.

Comment: There is no such setting in `v1.73.1` apparently.

Comment: Or in version 1.85.1

Answer (score 9):

I had this issue with VSCode `1.52.1`, the fix that worked for me was:

1. Disable `debug.javascript.usePreview` via Code > Preferences > Settings
2. Add `"localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/"` to launch.json
3. Add `"remoteRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/"` to launch.json

Comment: My lord, thank you. Step 1 only worked for me.

Comment: fantastic! thanks sir, with some modification it fixed my problem.
I use typescript and the localRoot and remoteRoot address must point to index.ts folder

Answer (score 5):

The plain truth is that VSCode 1.20 does not allow you to hit breakpoints.

I tried 1.21 too, it also does not let you do it.

I went back to 1.18 and it works just as expected, no problem.

Comment: It wasn't working for me in 1.25, I downgraded to 1.23.1 and it works again, the breakpoints are hit. Thanks.

Comment: Confirmed this is the case with my VS code too. Downgrading to 1.23 I could debug again.

Comment: This isn't really an answer - more of a comment.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue...
After i try a lot of launch config combinations, i found the correctly.

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "attach",
  "name": "Attach Program",
  "protocol": "inspector",
  "restart": true,
  "skipFiles": [
    "<node_internals>/**"
  ],
  "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "remoteRoot": "/",
}
```

Ps: I'm launch node script with nodemon using the --inspect parameter (that allow debugger to attach node).

Answer (score 4):

I faced this issue as recently as yesterday after upgrading to VSCode 1.52.1. Debugger which was previously working fine suddenly started showing "Unbound Breakpoint". This was happening for all the breakpoints I was trying to set regardless of the place/file/line in code. I then had to add the "localRoot" property and make it point to my source code folder for it to start working again. Hope this helps. My launch.json configuration now looks like this

```
    {
        "name": "Attach by Process ID",
        "processId": "${command:PickProcess}",
        "request": "attach",
        "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**"
        ],
        "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/Source",
        "type": "pwa-node"
    }
```

Comment: Faced the same issue in 1.52.1 but with web project and Chrome debugger. Adding source directory to the "webRoot" path fixed it.

Comment: Same problem here. All js breakpoints become unbound as soon as Chrome opens in debug session.

Answer (score 3):

For me, just adding `"localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"` to my default `launch.json` Configuration did the trick.

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Program",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/www",
    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For me the problem was that I forgot to set `"sourceMap": true` in my `tsconfig.json` file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party but wanted to share what was causing my "Unbound Breakpoint" errors.

I have file A and B.  File A called into File B (and was `require`d at the top of File A).  File A's breakpoints were working perfectly.  File B's sometimes let me hit them but I wasn't getting the full debugging experience if it worked at all.

I finally realized the `require` statement at the top of File A had different casing than the actual folder structure.  It was `require`ing `/path/to/file`, where it should have been `/Path/To/File`.

I fixed the path casing and the breakpoints in File B starting working again.

Comment: My breakpoints were hitting and highlighting in every file except one. In this one file the breakpoints showed as unbound hollow circles, it would hit, but no highlight and no values, mouseover would show definitions like when not debugging.  My original spelling in the require() was lowercase, and even after editing to camelcase this continued, until I copy/pasted the variable from the require(), to its creation statement, even though it was the same, pasting over the top suddenly highlighting was normal again. Well done @JasonAnderson. Even if it looks the same, copy and paste over them all.

Answer (score 1):

The very first thing you should check is the entry point - the first line of code that gets executed.  If that one can bound a breakpoint, then you know your other breakpoints are unbound because something between the time your other breakpoints are met is pre-empted by an error introduced.  Your code is not reachable in that case and the IDE can detect that your module is not loaded at all.

Answer (score 1):

If all this doesnt work - consider starting your vsCode in the correct folder
(the root directory, e.g. C:\Users\user\programming\RandomApp).

This is also why some people need to specify "/src" to their workspace variable (just a wild guess) and others dont.

Start it in the correct Folder and you dont need the /src parts in the launch.json file.

for me this launch.json works with vscode version 1.59.1

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "pwa-chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
        "url": "http://localhost:8100",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have a TypeScript project, which suddenly didn't hit breakpoints anymore. In my case I had to move the project folder out of my iCloud Drive folder. There were other indicators that this path wasn’t ok, like missing git gutter indicators, as well. Here is my debug launch config. Breakpoints placed in `app.ts` are being hit.

```
  {
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Debug",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/app.ts",
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "protocol": "inspector",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "outFiles": [
      "${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this configuration for debugging a TypeScript project:

```
        {
            "name": "Debug API",
            "request": "attach",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "type": "pwa-node",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**/*.js",
                "!**/node_modules/**"
            ]
        },
```

`outFiles` did the trick and bound my breakpoints (VS Code 1.51.1).

Answer (score 0):

I am running Docker Compose with the VSCode debugger and in my case, some of the breakpoints I set show unbounded and some show as bounded, even after trying the solutions above.

It seems the unbounded ones are outside of functions (on require or variable initialization statements for example).

I can only assume this is because the debugger attach runs after the docker containers have started (and hence these breakpoints are unreachable).

Answer (score 0):

@alkasai has the correct answer.

But, it also matters which source code folder was added to your workspace.  My repository structure is as such:  C:\git\parent_folder\child_folder\src

My breakpoints were not working, so long as 'parent_folder' was the folder added to my workspace and my 'webRoot' entry looked like this:

```
"webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
```

But, if I added '/child_folder' to 'webRoot' (e.g. "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/child_folder"), the breakpoints worked.

However, if I removed 'parent_folder' from my VS Code workspace, and instead added 'child_folder' to the workspace (thus changing the underlying value of the '${workspaceRoot}' variable value), the original entry (without the '/child_folder' subfolder reference) caused the breakpoints to be activated.

Answer (score 0):

Just for record, I use ts-node (esm), I changed `"args":["${file}"]` to `"args":["${workspaceFolder}/IHaveToSpecifyDamnFileName.ts"]` in launch.json and boom, it worked. I don't know why, but fvck microsoft!

Answer (score 0):

I have absolutely no idea why this worked for me but it did.  I was running VS Code 1.85.1 with node 18.18.x.  I upgraded to the latest LTS 20.10.0 and breakpoints are working again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this first after adding few break points:

```
Debug: toggle auto attach
```

I choose [smart](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_auto-attach) attach.

I ran from the integrated terminal `node run web` (the script I want to debug), it said debugger attached, but didn't stop at the break point.
Then I tried:

```
debug: javascript debug terminal
```

and ran `node run web` from it, now the script stops at the break point.

Answer (score -1):

To hit breakpoints you need to compile in debug mode. 
So when compiling the code using your `tasks.json` have debug flags enabled in your `command` attribute. C++ example :

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Compile Test",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "g++ -g test.cpp",
      "presentation": {
        "echo": true,
        "reveal": "always",
        "focus": false,
        "panel": "shared",
        "showReuseMessage": true,
        "clear": true
      },
      "group": "build",
    }
  ]
}
```

I am talking about the `-g` flag in the `"command": "g++ -g test.cpp",`