# How to debug Angular universal?

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal

I am using [Angular Universal Starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) repo. In angular 4 universal for ssr we could debug browser and node part of application in dev mode(see console), but now I do not see way to debug node part. I tried to execute `ts-node server.ts` with some changes( paths to files, etc), but angular seems needs **aot** compiled app and

> throw Error: You must pass in a NgModule or NgModuleFactory to be
>   bootstrapped.

from docs:

> Development (Client-side only rendering)
>    - run npm run start which will start ng serve
>
> Production (also for testing SSR/Pre-rendering locally)
>   - npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr

At first glance debug on Node.js in development do not work. At least from the box. May be someone resolve this issue.

Comment: Is it possible to use a service instead of the intense workload of Universal? Google bot should now be rendering SPAs just fine without it anyways: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2019/05/the-new-evergreen-googlebot.html

Comment: Perhaps build the app and execute `node --inspect` manually.

Answer (score 0):

Install the `ts-node` package.

```bash
npm install ts-node
```

Create a new launch configuration in your IDE for `server.ts`.

Set the type of the launch configuration to node.

Set the program of the launch configuration to `server.ts`.

Set the nodeArgs of the launch configuration to `-r ts-node`.

Start the debugger in your IDE.

This will start the Node.js server in debug mode. You can then step through your code and set breakpoints as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using VSCode I always debug my server side code with the help of Javascript Debug Terminal. Any node process that is started in this terminal has a debugger attached to it. The compilation of your code might be slower as having a debugger attached to it also. To open one use `cmd+shift+P` of `ctrl+shift+P` and search for `Debug: JavaScript Debug Terminal`.

Run your snippet like `npm run dev:ssr` in your terminal and the breakpoints will be used during rendering the app server side.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways depending on what you want to achieve to debug @angular/ssr (@angular/universal before Angular 17) i.e.:

1. One nice way for apps like Angular SSR and Express that depend on the https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug package is to use DEBUG environment variable.
   In Linux you can prefix the command with ad-hoc environment variable and run it like this: `DEBUG=* npm run serve` or `DEBUG=* npm run serve:ssr:testapp`. A fine article which also shows processes and error levels you can put instead of `*` here: https://dev.to/aderchox/what-is-the-debug-environment-variable-in-nodejs-and-how-to-use-it-3fal
   Example output:

> [image]

2. Use Node.js' inspector https://nodejs.org/en/learn/getting-started/debugging for example `node --inspect ./node_modules/.bin/ng serve` or `node --inspect dist/testapp/server/server.mjs` and then click on the green octagon in DevTools. This in turn, allows for measuring the performance and other fancy stuff of your Node.js app:

> [image]

3. Use breakpoints in IDE ;) Check the setup of VSCode to debug Node.js here: [Visual Studio Code - Node debugger breakpoints not being hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46821519/visual-studio-code-node-debugger-breakpoints-not-being-hit)

Answer (score -1):

You can't debug node part of your Angular 4 app in browser. Node work on server part so you can't see this in browser (client side).

Only way to debug this part when you start it from `ts-node server.ts` is to use external tools like WebStorm etc. If you start your App in TS mode from `Debug mode` you can use all features of this tools.

Comment: as i said, we cannot debug node part because of in dev application not using node part (Client-side only rendering) at all

Comment: But you can always start ssr aplication in dev mode and debug it.

Answer (score -1):

I think this small piece of code can help you

## create the project

```
ng n debuggable-universal-server --interactive=false

cd debuggable-universal-server
```

## add universal

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject debuggable-universal-server
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: This generates a new project but helps nothing with debugging.

Answer (score -5):

To create the server-side app module, app.server.module.ts, run the following CLI command.

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine
```

To start rendering your app with Universal on your local system, use the following command.

```
npm run dev:ssr
```